# Doxygen fails to process header files in Fortran code

Tags: fortran, doxygen

I have a mature Fortran code which I would like to modernise and as part of this process incorporate doxygen comments throughout. The code contains header files which contain lists of variables (and previously common blocks) that could then be included in subroutines where access to these variables are required. Regardless of what I do, I can not get doxygen(1.8.13) to process these files. I have written a simpler example involving three files below to show what I mean:

**MODULE.f**

```
!> @brief An example of a module with global variables defined
!> @details The purpose is to explain why the global variables in group VARGROUP2 in the included file do not appear in the doxygen output.
!> @details Why? Please help! I can not see where I have made a mistake
      MODULE EXAMPLE
      INTEGER N
      PARAMETRER(N=10)

!> @name VARGROUP1
!! Parameters in group 1
!> @{ 
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_VECTOR(N)               !< An example of a global vector variable
!> @}
#include "VARIABLES.h"
!> @name VARGROUP3
!! Parameters in group 3
!> @{ 
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR3_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR3_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
!> @}

      CONTAINS
!> @brief An example of a subroutine within a module
!> @details A simple Hello World Program
      SUBROUTINE EXSUB
      INTEGER I                                    !< Example of a local variable
      I = 0
      GR1_GLOBAL1 = 0
      GR2_GLOBAL1 = 0
      WRITE(*,*) 'HELLO WORLD'
      WRITE(*,*) I,GR1_GLOBAL1,GR2_GLOBAL1
      END SUBROUTINE EXSUB
      END MODULE EXAMPLE
```

The included header file (VARIABLES.h):

```
!> @name VARGROUP2
!! Parameters in group 2
!> @{ 
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR2_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR2_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
!> @}
```

And for completeness, the FORTRAN program which makes use of this module (PROG.f):

```
  PROGRAM PROG
  USE EXAMPLE
  CALL EXSUB
  END
```

When I try to doxygen this, the HTML output successfully shows VARGROUP1 and VARGROUP3. However, VARGROUP2 (as defined in the VARIABLES.h file) are not present. I have tried many options in doxygen such as `FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES`, `ENABLE_PREPOSSESSING`, `MACRO_EXPANSION` and `SEARCH_INCLUDES`.

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated.

Note I tried this all with 1.8.13 (the version that can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 with apt-get). I have since experimented with a more recent version (1.8.19) but this makes matters even worse, since now none of the variable groups appear !!

For completeness, below is the doxygen configuration (generated by doxywizard), taking into account Albert's comments:

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.13

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Example which does not work"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /home/USER/SCRATCH/OFFICIAL_CHANGE/TEST/doxytest/OUTPUT
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = "EXTENSION_MAPPING= .h=fortran"
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = YES
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = YES
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = YES
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = YES
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = /home/USER/SCRATCH/OFFICIAL_CHANGE/TEST/doxytest
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = YES
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             = 
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
DIA_PATH               = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = 
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      = 
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Comment: Most likely problem is that your `.h` file is seen a C file and not as a Fortran file. Probably a solution night be to the set `EXTENSION_MAPPING= .h=fortran`, assuming your project does not have any real C `.h` files.

Comment: Note the typo in `PARAMETRER(N=10)`!

Comment: Thanks Albert for comments. I added the extension mapping as suggested but unfortunately this didn't help. Assuming the problem was doxygen thinking .h files are C, I changed the extension to .f but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Regarding typo, TBH, I didn't try to compile!

Comment: You should always only offer valid code to doxygen or stringe things can happen (probably not in this case, but in case of a misspelled `SUBROUTINE` , `END` or other flow keyword)

Comment: Hi, I fixed the typo and the code compiles fine in gfortran (gfortran -c -cpp MODULE.f; gfortran -c PROG.f; gfortran -o prog MODULE.o PROG.o)

Comment: I think I know the background of the problem. Doxygen is not a compiler and handles every file separately, so every file has to be a complete and valid Fortran file. With complete I mean contain a Program, Subroutine / function or Module. In the include file this is not the case. A possible workaround would be to make a make a `.F` file out of it (so it will be preprocessed) and plce on top something like `#ifdef DOXYGEN\nMODULE INCLUDED\n#endif` and at the end the complementing `#ifdef DOXYGEN\nEND MODULE\n#endif`, not nice but...I think it probably won't land in the docs of `EXAMPLE` though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Albert for all your input. I am now in a position to suggest an answer to my question and summarise where I went wrong.

The problem is that although the code originally posted is correct from the perspective of the compiler, Doxygen expects each file to be a function, subroutine, module or main. Therefore, to 'trick' Doxygen into thinking the code is valid, a couple #ifdef statements can be used to make it appear to Doxygen it is a MODULE (see VARIABLES.h below). Note that from the compiler's perspective, it is not fooled and does not class the contents of the header file as a module.

The other change required was to the configuration of Doxygen since a .h file will be processed as a C header file. Therefore, extension mapping is required to redefine all .h files to be fortran (see the doxywizard configuration output below).

The three files are now the following:

```
!> @brief An example of a module with global variables defined
!> @details The purpose is to explain why the global variables in group VARGROUP2 in the included file do not appear in the DOXYGEN ouptut.
!> @details Why? Please help! I can not see where I have made a mistake
!> @details I added the suggestion made by Albert and also renamed the header file to a fortran F file
      MODULE EXAMPLE
      INTEGER N                                    !< Size of vector
      PARAMETER(N=10)

!> @name VARGROUP1 
!! Parameters in group 1
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable 
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR1_VECTOR(N)               !< An example of a global vector variable
!> @}
#include "VARIABLES.h"
!> @name VARGROUP3 
!! Parameters in group 3
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR3_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR3_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
!> @}

      CONTAINS
!> @brief An example of a subroutine within a module
!> @details A simple Hello World Program
      SUBROUTINE EXSUB
      INTEGER I                                    !< Example of a local variable
      I = 0
      GR1_GLOBAL1 = 1
      GR2_GLOBAL1 = 2
      GR3_GLOBAL1 = 3
      WRITE(*,*) 'HELLO WORLD'
      WRITE(*,*) I,GR1_GLOBAL1,GR2_GLOBAL1,GR3_GLOBAL1
      END SUBROUTINE EXSUB
      END MODULE EXAMPLE
```

The contents of the file that is included is as follows (VARIABLES.h). The #ifdef constructs are the important bits:

```
#ifdef DOXYGEN
      MODULE VARGROUP2
#endif
!> @name VARGROUP2 
!! Parameters in group 2
!> @{ 
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR2_GLOBAL1                 !< Example of a global variable
      DOUBLE PRECISION GR2_GLOBAL2                 !< Another example of a global variable
!> @}
#ifdef DOXYGEN
      END
#endif
```

For completeness, the FORTRAN code that utilises the EXAMPLE module and creates the program is as follows:

```
  PROGRAM PROG
  USE EXAMPLE
  CALL EXSUB
  END
```

Also, the doxygen configuration (as outputted by doxywizard) is as follows, noting the need to use extension mapping to force doxygen into thinking .h files contain fortran code:

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.13

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Example Module"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = /home/rwhg1/SCRATCH/OFFICIAL_CHANGE/TEST/doxytest
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = f=FortranFixed \
                         h=FortranFixed
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 0
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = YES
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = /home/rwhg1/SCRATCH/OFFICIAL_CHANGE/TEST/doxytest
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *..h
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             = 
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
DIA_PATH               = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = /usr/bin/dot
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = 
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      = 
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

The resulting HTML output from Doxygen shows the contents of the header file as a module, which is obviously incorrect. This workaround is hopefully good enough, but if anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I opted to write a FORTRAN program which pre-processes the FORTRAN file to be processed by DOXYGEN. The purpose of this program was to replace all instances of #include "filename.xxx" with the contents of filename.xxx. Initially, this was used to ensure the contents of the header files were processed properly (without the need to set up 'fake' modules to contain the variables). However, it was also useful to separate the function descriptions (i.e. the @brief and @details cards) as some of these were very long! Anyway, I thought this might be useful for the community (use at your own risk):

```
!> @brief A program that inserts all included files into a FORTRAN input file
!> @details Requires two inputs:
!> @details 1/. the FORTRAN input file containing '#include' directives
!> @details 2./ the output filename for the new FORTRAN input file
        PROGRAM MAIN
        IMPLICIT NONE
        CHARACTER*1000 ARG1,ARG2,INCFILE
        CHARACTER*90000 BUFFER
        LOGICAL YESNO
        INTEGER CONT,IE,COUNTER

! ****  Get original FORTRAN file to which included files to be added
        CALL GETARG(1,ARG1)
! ****  Get name of new FORTRAN file
        CALL GETARG(2,ARG2)
C ****  Check file exists already
        INQUIRE(FILE=ARG1,EXIST=YESNO)
        IF(YESNO) THEN
          OPEN(10,FILE=ARG1,STATUS='OLD')
        ELSE
          STOP
        ENDIF

C ****  Check output file does not exist
        INQUIRE(FILE=ARG2,EXIST=YESNO)
        IF(YESNO) THEN
          WRITE(*,'(A)') 'OUTPUT FILE ALREADY EXISTS'
          STOP
        ENDIF
        OPEN(20,FILE=ARG2,STATUS='NEW')

C ****  Loop through input file. If pre-processor directive
C       '#include' exists, then call INSERTINCLUDE. If not then simply
C       copy the line to the output file
        CONT = 0
        COUNTER = 20
        DO WHILE(CONT.GE.0)
          READ(10,'(A)',END=999) BUFFER
          IF(BUFFER(1:8).EQ.'#include') THEN
            COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
            CALL INSERTINCLUDE(BUFFER,COUNTER)
          ELSE
            WRITE(20,'(A)') TRIM(BUFFER)
          ENDIF
        ENDDO
 999    CONTINUE

        CLOSE(10)
        CLOSE(20)
        END

!> @brief A recursive subroutine which replaces an '#include' line with the contents of the file being referenced
!> @details Subroutine is recursive so can include files that are included within another included file
!> @details Useful to keep lengthy Doxygen comments separate from the actual code aswell
        RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE INSERTINCLUDE(BUFFER,COUNTER)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        CHARACTER*90000 BUFFER                                      !> A character buffer which is hopefully large enough to hold the contents of each line in the included file (also initially contains the '#include' line with the file to be opened)
        CHARACTER*1000 INCFILE                                      !> Included file to be opened
        INTEGER COUNTER                                             !> A unique LUN number for the included file which increments by 1 for every recursive instance of this subroutine
        INTEGER IE,CONT2,NEXTCOUNTER
        LOGICAL YESNO
C ****  DETERMINE THE DOUBLE QUOTATION MARKS SURROUNDING THE FILE TO BE INCLUDED
        WRITE(*,'(A)') TRIM(BUFFER)
        IE = INDEX(BUFFER,'"')
        INCFILE = BUFFER(IE+1:)
        IE = INDEX(INCFILE,'"')
        INCFILE = INCFILE(1:IE-1)
        WRITE(*,'(2A)') 'INCLUDING ',TRIM(INCFILE)
C ****  CHECK THE FILE TO BE INCLUDED EXISTS. IF YES THEN OPEN
        INQUIRE(FILE=INCFILE,EXIST=YESNO)
        IF(YESNO) THEN
          OPEN(COUNTER,FILE=INCFILE,STATUS='OLD')
        ELSE
          WRITE(*,'(A)') 'COULD NOT OPEN INCLUDE FILE'
          STOP
        ENDIF
C ****  LOOP THROUGH THE INCLUDED FILE AND COPY CONTENTS TO LUN 20 (I.E. THE MAIN OUTPUT FILE)
C       IF ANOTHER '#include' IS FOUND THEN RUN ANOTHER INSTANCE OF THIS SUBROUTINE
        CONT2 = 0
        DO WHILE(CONT2.GE.0)
          READ(COUNTER,'(A)',END=888) BUFFER
          IF(BUFFER(1:8).EQ.'#include') THEN
            NEXTCOUNTER = COUNTER + 1
            CALL INSERTINCLUDE(BUFFER,NEXTCOUNTER)
          ELSE
            WRITE(20,'(A)') TRIM(BUFFER)
          ENDIF
        ENDDO
 888    WRITE(*,'(2A)') 'FINISHED INCLUDING ',TRIM(INCFILE)
        CLOSE(COUNTER)
        END
```

There is no doubt an easier way probably, but this worked for me.